# My API is erroneously reporting that GitHub Pages' IP is private. How do I fix this and get the real IP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, github-pages

I am aiming to whitelist the IP addresses that may access my API. In doing so, I've added a logging middleware that documents the IP addresses of each API request:

```
function loggingMiddleware(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.path+' request received from req.ip: ' + req.ip+ ', req.connection.remoteAddress: '+req.connection.remoteAddress+', req.secure: '+req.secure);
    next();
}
```

*[(Here's some documentation for the Node.js `req` object).](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_request_object.htm)*

The approved client of my API is a site hosted on GitHub's Pages. I know that GitHub uses the following IPs to host the websites on their platform:

- 185.199.108.153
- 185.199.109.153
- 185.199.110.153
- 185.199.111.153

With this in mind, when my API is called, I expect the logging middleware to say that one of the IPs in the list sent the request, however that is not the case. I used the GitHub Pages site to send a request and the following log entry was made:

```
2019-03-16T23:43:35.094993+00:00 app[web.1]: / request received from req.ip: ::ffff:10.47.166.118, req.connection.remoteAddress: ::ffff:10.47.166.118, req.secure: false
```

(The important part is `req.ip: ::ffff:10.47.166.118`)

This IP address is private and is not one of GitHub Pages.

With all this in mind, my questions is: How is it possible that the `req.ip` results in a private IP when I used GitHub pages to make the request? How do I correctly access the expected GitHub Pages IP?